# GitHub change from password to access token failed

Tags: github, phpstorm

I used the password authentication for GitHub. Today changed. I just removed in PhpStorm the GitHub Account and created a new one with the NEW CREATED ACCESS TOKEN (with full repo access, also private).

I restarted PhpStorm. But if I push or pull I still get the error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the current PW Git auth from the OS credential store, to make sure it doesn't get used anymore.

In Windows: To open **Credential Manager**, type credential manager in the search box on the taskbar and select Credential Manager Control panel. Select Web Credentials or Windows Credentials to access the credentials you want to manage.

Mac: Keychain App

Linux: Often libsecret, and can be managed with gnome-keyring/Seahorse/Password app

Find the entries for GitHub.com and delete them.
You may also try to do a `git fetch` on CLI after that, to make Git prompt you and add the new entry.

Comment: So far I connected in PHPstorm with GitHub. But if I try to update project, I get popup: "Can't update master has no tracked branch". But its master.